# Convert Object to ObjectArray but the Array should have the Type of the Object

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection

I've a function wich Converts a Object to a Object Array.

I know I can do this

```
new [] {obj}
```

but then the Array is of Type object[]. I want that the Array is of the Type of whatever obj.GetType() returns!

Is this possible in a performant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a static method of the Array class.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb3cfh7k.aspx

The full example could be

```
object o = ...;// Some object you want to convert into a an array
var arrayVar = Array.CreateInstance(o.GetType(), 1);
```

Comment: You have almost reached a good answer. Why not expand it to show how it would be used to achieve what the OP wants?

Answer (score 1):

```
T[] ToObjectArray<T>(T item)
{
    return new T[] { item };
}
```

You can use it like

```
int[] arr1 = ToObjectArray(5);
Color[] arr2 = ToObjectArray(Color.Red);
```

Comment: It will return an array of type item is seen as by compiler, not the one it actually is (the one returned by `obj.GetType`). Unless you use `dynamic`.